# Is there a faster alternative to check if a SELECT statement is null in CASE statements in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, select, case, isnull, case-statement

Is there a faster version for this case statement?

```
CASE
 WHEN (SELECT STATEMENT) IS NOT NULL
 THEN (SELECT STATEMENT)
 ELSE 0
END AS [Variable Name]
```

Where the `SELECT STATEMENT`doesn't change from line 2 to line 3.

Thank you!

Comment: how much column does you Select statement has?

Comment: Faster to type or faster to execute? :)

Comment: I look for something faster to execute.The select statement anyway returns just one value.

Comment: ISNULL is the fastest then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster to type...

```
isnull(statement, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT co11
    FROM ...
)
SELECT ISNULL(cte.col1, 0) as [Variable Name]
FROM cte
```